# Can we use factory_boy in a project hosts in pythonanywhere

Tags: django, pythonanywhere, factory-boy

I have a simple question about factory_boy and pythonanywhere. Does someone know whether or not we can include  the factory_boy library in a project hosts in Pythonanywhere?

Comment: Why would you think you can't? But I also can't see why you would want to. Factory_boy is for testing; you shouldn't be running your tests in production.

Comment: To answer your first question, because I didn't see it in the list within: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/batteries_included/ I already had an issue with two liobrarties when I install my website. So, now, each time I don't see the package in their list, I have a reasonnable doubt.

Comment: Regarding your second question I am going to use this package in each test.py for all app. So I suppose that even if I don't run test in production, I can have problem when I am going to push the new version on Pythonanywhere. Am I wrong in my way of thinking? What do you recommand?

Comment: This help page might be useful if you want to know how to install Python packages on PythonAnywhere: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/